# If JSONP is just dynamic script, when is the request made?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

Apparently JSONP requests using jQuery.ajax is not really asynchronous, rather it just uses the Script DOM Element approach, adding a script tag to the page. I discovered that from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-dev/5-tKI-7zQvs, which states:

> Cross-domain JSONP isn't AJAX at all. It doesn't use XMLHttpRequest.
>   It's nothing more than a dynamic script element that loads JavaScript
>   code.

That dynamic script element is then processed after the page has loaded (and in the case of JSONP, that just means the callback function is executed with a parameter of the JSON data sourced from the url specified in the .ajax call).

So if I had the following code in an HTML web page:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({dataType:'jsonp', data:'FIRST'...});
    });
</script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({dataType:'jsonp', data:'SECOND'...});
    });
</script>
```

what would the order of things be?

Would it be either:

(1) script tag to do FIRST request added to DOM

(2) script tag to do SECOND request added to DOM

(3) FIRST request made

(4) SECOND request made

or:

(1) script tag to do FIRST request added to DOM

(2) FIRST request made

(3) script tag to do SECOND request added to DOM

(4) SECOND request made

or maybe neither of the above and I am misunderstanding?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Apparently JSONP requests using jQuery.ajax is not really asynchronous

That's wrong, they are.

> rather it just uses the Script DOM Element approach, adding a script tag to the page.

That's true.

> Cross-domain JSONP isn't AJAX at all. It doesn't use XMLHttpRequest.

XMLHttpRequest is not a prerequisite for Ajax. (And XML isn't a prerequisite for either Ajax or XMLHttpRequest (which only got XML in its name because XML was cool at the time and the developers needed to convince managers to add it to the product))

> what would the order of things be?

1. The first script would run (creating a ready event handler)
2. The second script would run (creating a second ready event handler)
3. The ready event would fire
4. The first dynamic script element would be added to the page
5. The second dynamic script element would be added to the page
6. The first dynamic script element would execute
7. The second dynamic script element would execute

Comment: Note however that 6 and 7 may happen in reverse depending on how long each request takes.

Comment: @Quentin We observe browser memory keeps increasing as every time a new "<Script .....>" tag is added the browsers downloads the same as a "File" which it seems to cache - Disabling cache may not help as we are having to make recursive calls without refreshing/reloading the page when the tab is open - We observe the memory bloat to upto 800MB before crashing. - any help to circumvent this ?